# Magento1.7 - Add optional fee over order

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

How can I add an optional 10% fee over the whole order? I want my customers to be able to choose between no fee or a optional 10% fee (with some advantages for them).

At this moment, I've tried to represent this by enabling "Free shipping" and "Flat rate". 
So at `System/Configuration/Shipping Methods` I've put the following values:

```
 - 'Handling Fee' => '0.10' 
 - 'Calculate Handling Fee'=>'Percent'
 - 'Type' => 'Per order'
```

As a result, the generated orders have a '10 cents' fee, instead of a percentage over its value.

How does can I represent this with Magento? Should I use Flat rates?

PS: I'm testing it only with back-end, should I face any difference compared with end user?

Comment: You could solve this with this modification: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933462/magento-charge-shipping-as-percentage-of-subtotal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved what I was looking for by editing `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php` by adding the following method

```
protected function _getPerorderPrice($cost, $handlingType, $handlingFee){ 
 if ($handlingType == self::HANDLING_TYPE_PERCENT) {
   $val = ($cost * $this->_numBoxes * $handlingFee);
   return $val;
 }
 return ($cost * $this->_numBoxes)  $handlingFee;
}
```

and by changing the line 78 to:

```
$shippingPrice = $request->getPackageValue();
```

I'm not sure if this will cause any side-effect, so please comment if you identify any :)
At this moment everything seems to be working fine.